# Adding new speaker to a pre-trained speaker recognition model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, voice-recognition, gmm

I have trained a deep neural network for speaker recognition(Trained on 64 different speakers).Next I want to add or delete a speaker from the model. Can anyone help me out with the coding part on how to do it, as I am new to voice recognition. Even any research paper that someone knows of can be helpful.

P.s. If I use a new dataset on the pre-trained model then I need to train the model again on new 64 speakers. Considering I just want to add or delete 1 or 2 speaker, how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is to measure the similarity (as often done in speaker verification) instead of the logits layer you have trained on the initial dataset (with 64 speakers).

When feeding an input audio to the speaker recognition model, you can take the hidden layer values right before the logits layer and use it as an utterance-level feature. (let's call this speaker embedding vector)

Let us say that you have a new dataset with M utterances and N speakers (disjoint from the initial training set).
From this dataset, you can extract M embedding vectors using your pre-trained network.

Average the embedding vectors with the same speaker, you will get M speaker-specific embedding vectors. We will call these enrolled vectors.

Then to test a new speech sample, you simply have to extract the embedding vector from the test speech and compare its similarity with the M enrolled vectors (usually cosine similarity is used for speaker verification).
For P test utterances, this will give you a [P x M] matrix. For each test utterance, you can select the language with the highest similarity to perform speaker identification.

By doing this, you can perform speaker identification without re-training the network you have trained for speakers not included in the test set.

If you wish to learn some classical/popular methods used for speaker recognition, you can check the following paper out:

J. H. L. Hansen and T. Hasan, "Speaker recognition by machines and humans: a tutorial review," IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, vol. 32, no. 6, 2015.